# Predicting using raster stack/brick - returns "object is not a matrix"

Tags: r

I have created a raster stack, and wish to use it to predict features based on a GLM  model.

```
#creating the raster /raster stack
Waterdis <- raster('waterdist.tif')
Shoredis <- raster('Shoredist.tif')
IceConcRaster<- raster('Iceconc.tif')
Bathy <- raster('bathtry.tif')

crs(Bathy) <- "+init=EPSG:4326"
plot(Bathy)

#Projecting to right coordinate system
Bathy_Proj <- projectRaster(Bathy, crs="+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=45 +lon_0=50 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
plot(Bathy_Proj)

#resampling to bathymetry raster
#Shore distance
ShoreRaster <- resample(Shoredis,Bathy_Proj, method="ngb")
#water distance
WaterRaster <- resample(Waterdis,Bathy_Proj, method="ngb")
#ice concentration 
IceConcRasterres <- resample(IceConcRaster,Bathy_Proj, method="ngb")

#stacking predictors 
predictors2pre <- stack(list(WaterRaster=WaterRaster, IceConcRasterres=IceConcRasterres, ShoreRaster=ShoreRaster,Bathy_Proj=Bathy_Proj))
plot(predictors2pre)
```

The model was a binary logistic regression. I have managed to use the predict function using another raster stack on the same model, but not with the "predictors2pre" stack.

```
#the raster stack in question -   predictors2pre         
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 2856, 2466, 7042896, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 353, 473  (x, y)
extent     : -397756.4, 472741.6, -5536805, -4185917  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=45 +lon_0=50 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : /private/var/folders/qd/785_ds8j4fn0xphk7604q4f80000gn/T/Rtmpy9oiyR/raster/r_tmp_2019-07-20_123308_1328_18877.grd 
names      : WaterRaster, IceConcRasterres, ShoreRaster,  Bathy_Proj 
min values :   2209.7087,           0.0000,    179.3362, -13175.5049 
max values :  284091.562,          255.000,  184013.016,    2164.948



#Predicting features
M2ThickIpred.ALL <- predict(predictors2pre, M2ThickIce.ALL.Years, type='response')
The output returns this error  - 

#"Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action,
# xlev = object$xlevels) :
# 
#   object is not a matrix"
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducible example. If you struggle with that you should still provide more information (code), including to show how you formulated your model. At this point you do not even show what type of model it is

Comment: Thank you for your edits, but you are showing how you are manipulating raster data. Instead you could use existing data.. You need to show how you formulated your model --- that is key here.

Comment: Also, instead of `Bathy_Proj <- projectRaster(Bathy, crs="+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=45 +lon_0=50 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m")` you should probably do  `Bathy_Proj <- projectRaster(Bathy, Shoredis)` to avoid resampling

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reproducible example that works. Can you break it by more closely following what you did? And show that using these data?

```
library(raster)
logo <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
logo
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 77, 101, 7777, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent     : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=merc +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#source     : C:/soft/R/R-3.6.1/library/raster/external/rlogo.grd 
#names      : red, green, blue 
#min values :   0,     0,    0 
#max values : 255,   255,  255 

# presence and absence points
p <- matrix(c(48, 48, 48, 53, 50, 46, 54, 70, 84, 85, 74, 84, 95, 85, 
   66, 42, 26, 4, 19, 17, 7, 14, 26, 29, 39, 45, 51, 56, 46, 38, 31, 
   22, 34, 60, 70, 73, 63, 46, 43, 28), ncol=2)
a <- matrix(c(22, 33, 64, 85, 92, 94, 59, 27, 30, 64, 60, 33, 31, 9,
   99, 67, 15, 5, 4, 30, 8, 37, 42, 27, 19, 69, 60, 73, 3, 5, 21,
   37, 52, 70, 74, 9, 13, 4, 17, 47), ncol=2)

xy <- rbind(cbind(1, p), cbind(0, a))
v <- data.frame(cbind(pa=xy[,1], extract(logo, xy[,2:3])))

model <- glm(formula=pa~., data=v, family=binomial(link="logit"))
model

#Call:  glm(formula = pa ~ ., family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = v)
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)          red        green         blue  
#   283.5023      -6.5323       4.5612       0.6848  
#Degrees of Freedom: 39 Total (i.e. Null);  36 Residual
#Null Deviance:      55.45 
#Residual Deviance: 2.711e-09    AIC: 8

r <- predict(logo, model, type="response")
```